# Guest OS not able to ping switch gateway IP from VM if bridge networking selected

Tags: networking

I have vmware workstaion and number  of guest OS has been installed with that. Problem is the Vmware machine is able to ping the external gateway switch(directly connected) but the guest OS are not able to ping switch. The switch has configured with mac authentication so all the clients mac address are updated in radius server database.all the clients should authenticated in radius server. The issue is occuring when we select bridge mode networking in workstation but under NAT mode we do not have this issue.

But if we remove the mac authentication configuration in switch, the issue is not occuring.
Is there any condition bridge mode will use only one MAC address?

Comment: The only way every device uses the same MAC is if you configure them that way. Good luck getting them to play together like that though ;)

Answer (score 4):

No.  That isn't how bridging works.  When you bridge two networks the bridging is supposed to be transparent and the same MAC address is used on both sides.

This actually represents port security working the way it is intended.  You are basically connecting a number of different computers to the port when you connect the hypervisor, and you should configure the switch accordingly.  Alternatively, you could set up all of your VMs to do the appropriate RADIUS authentication.

You can also route the connection locally on the hypervisor-running computer, instead of bridging.